# Ajax/Php Как получить данные с формы?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Прошу помощи)) 
Есть код который обрабатывает форму получает данные и вот не могу понять как на стороне php их получить?!!

```
function call() {
var msg = $('#formBalance').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax',
    data: msg,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
```

}

в скрипте по адресу /ajax пытаюсь получить ответ но как? 
PS. /ajax ведет к файлу .php

Comment: $test=$_POST['name_of_form_input'];

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, post или get запрос.

Post запрос, приблизительно так:

```
$myparam=$_POST['myparam'];
```

Для get запроса, приблизительно так:

```
$myparam=$_GET['myparam'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете данные в `data`, то есть передаете `msg`.
Поймать `msg` на стороне сервера можно так:

```
if($_POST['msg']){
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];
        echo "Данные приняты";
}
```

или

```
    if($_GET['msg']){
            $msg= $_GET['msg'];
            echo "Данные приняты";
    }
```

И увидеть результат в браузере, получив ответ:

```
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Отправляем ajax запрос на сервер */
function responseAjax() {
    console.log('Отправляем запрос на сервер');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            ajax: true,
            filterData: JSON.stringify(dataToServer)
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log('Данные с сервера пришли', data);
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log('Ошибка получения ответа с сервера', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
}
```